# Migrating database fails after upgrading to Ruby 2.3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm, ruby-2.3

I've updated to Ruby 2.3.0 and I'm having some issues when creating a new Rails app. After creating a simple new test app and scaffolding a resource, when trying to execute `rake db:migrate` I'm getting the following load error:

```
    MacBook-Pro:log medright1$ rake db:migrate
/Users/medright1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:31:in `require': cannot load such file -- rake (LoadError)
    from /Users/medright1/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/medright1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
    from /Users/medright1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/medright1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/medright1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
MacBook-Pro:log medright1$
```

Any help sorting this would be great!

Comment: Just a sanity check: did you `bundle` after upgrading Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't done it yet, make sure you have all the dependencies installed.

```
$ bundle
```

or

```
$ bundle install
```

It's likely you don't have `rake` installed in the global RVM gemset. In any case, given you are within a Rails project, you should use `bundler` to execute the command.

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Otherwise, make sure to install rake globally

```
$ rvm gemset use global
$ gem install rake
```

However, the correct way is to execute the command via Bundler.

Comment: Thank you very much Simone! The last two commands fixed the issue.. as I had previously had 2.2 versions of ruby installed with rails 4.2.5 apps running rake with no problems did I miss something in the upgrade to 2.3? I'm fairly new to programming and not really sure where I might have gone wrong here..

Comment: By default, `rake` is not installed in the global gemset (as in general you don't install gems in the global gemset). You may had it in a previous setup for some reason, and you didn't notice it hence you assumed it was the default behavior.